# What is the fastest possible checkmate?

Tags: checkmate

What is the fastest/shortest possible checkmate? What is the minimum amount of moves to checkmate a side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two moves! And this has a name as well! It is called [Fool's mate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fool%27s_mate)!

```
 [title "Fastest Mate"]
 [fen "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1"]

 1. f3? e5 2. g4?? Qh4++
```